# Show git changes in gutter against local/remote branch in PyCharm

Tags: git, pycharm

It is pretty convenient to see changes made locally on files in the gutter like shown [in jetbrain's docs](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Using+PyCharm's+Git+integration+locally#UsingPyCharm%27sGitintegrationlocally-Changingthecodeinthemasterbranch).

[image: in-editor view]

But it is possible to compare against another git branch instead of HEAD inside PyCharm's view ?

Example: I've made a couple of commits in the "work" branch (based on master) and I want to see the changes I've made against the master branch (i.e. `git diff master..work`).

Answer (score -2):

You can do it very easily:

```
git log ^branch1 branch2
or:
git log branch1 ^branch2
```

This will display the differences between the branches.
The is for displaying to which branch is your 'left/right' merged branch.

originally it will display `pull/push` changes before merging branches, and you can use it for your needs.

Comment: Thanks @codeWizard, but I meant directly in PyCharm's interface !
I edit my post to be more precise. I'm already using `git diff master..work` to do that in a terminal.

Comment: As far as i know since no GUI tool can support all the CLI options its not possible within the GUI itself.